# for loop specific file names R

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, file-copying

I have a list of identifiers saved as a character variable (uid_car)
I have a list of files (file_list) with an identifier as the prefix to file name(eg 1000_*.file)

uid_car<-1000,1002,1004....len(170)
file_list<-1000_01_.file,1001_02.file,1003_02.file,1002_01.file,1004_01.file...len(~700)

In the above example I want to loop through the file list and copy the files that have the prefix contained in uid_car. Therefore, only file 1000_01.file, 1002_01.file and 1004_01.file would be copied to a new path.

The following for loop below works until you hit an ith element not contained in uid_car.

I have tried an mapply function which is probably a bit neater but don't have as much experience writing these...any help would be appreciated.

```
for (i in length_of_file_list) {
  if (startsWith(file_list[i], uid_car[])) {
    file.copy(file_list[i], new_path)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you DO want to do it in a loop, this may do what you're looking for:

```
uids_to_print <- c("1000", "1001", "1004")
filenames <-c("1000_01.file","1000_02.file","1001_01.file","1001_02.file","1002_01.file","1002_02.file","1003_01.file","1004_01.file")


# Iterate through each filename
for (filename in filenames) {

    # Pull out the characters prior to the first underscore
    filename_uid <- unlist(strsplit(filename, "_"))[1]

    # Cheeck if it's in the list of ones to print
    if(filename_uid %in% uids_to_print) {
        # Put file operation inside this loop

    }
}
```

for example, executing

```
for (filename in filenames) {
    filename_uid <- unlist(strsplit(filename, "_"))[1]
    if(filename_uid %in% uids_to_print) {
        print(paste("copy", filename, sep=" "))
    }
}
```

yields

```
"copy 1000_01.file"
"copy 1000_02.file"
"copy 1001_01.file"
"copy 1001_02.file"
"copy 1004_01.file"
```

Comment: Thank-you very much, this has worked, in the last section of the for loop I used file.copy(paste(filename,sep= " "),new_path)..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a loop.

```
files.to.copy <- file_list[file_list %in% paste0(uid_car,'_01.file')]
file.copy(files.to.copy, new_path)
```

Comment: This would work, but not all files do not contain the same name after uid_car....

Comment: @e.matt I see.  I misunderstood what you wanted.  Seems like you already have a solution but a quick and dirty way would be to just change my first line to: `files.to.copy <- file_list[substr(file_list,1,4) %in% uid_car]`.  Assuming all the IDs in `uid_car` are 4 digits long.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this is a great alternate that is suitable, as ID's are 4 digits long.